# How do you "sordid sort" alphanumeric strings?

Tags: regex, perl, sorting

The question is about sorting alphanumeric string in a "more natural" order. Source: Marc LeBrun's "Sordid Sort" [Computist Quiz](http://fxpt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/quiz.pdf)

> Often a system string comparison sorts alphanumeric data “unnaturally”, as with these filenames:
>
> ```
> File1
> File10 ← ?
> File11 ← ?
> File12 ← ?
> File2
> File3
> File3X
> File4
> File5
> File6
> File7
> File8
> File999
> ```
>
> Describe an algorithm that will sort alphanumeric strings in a “more natural” order:
>
> ```
> File1
> File2
> File3
> File3X
> File4
> File5
> File6
> File7
> File8
> File10
> File11
> File12
> File999
> ```
>
> The algorithm may only rely on comparing characters; to avoid overflow problems with very long numbers it must not convert substrings of digits into their numerical values.

Spoiler alert: If you would like to independently solve the above, please do so now before you let the below spoil it for you.

This implementation has its inspiration from [Computist Quiz Answer Guide](http://fxpt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/QuizAnswers.pdf). Misunderstandings would be mine.

From the Answer Guide: Extra credit: discuss the behavior with respect to leading zeros, as in “007”.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Sordid Sort: http://fxpt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/quiz.pdf
# Solution based on http://fxpt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/QuizAnswers.pdf

use strict;

my $verbose = 0;    # set it to non-zero to get regex matches printed to STDERR
my $ALNUM = qr/(\D*)(\d*)/; # match a pair of alphas-optional and/or num-optional
my @in = ();

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @in, $_; 
}

sub sordidcmp {
    my @a = $a =~ m/$ALNUM/g;   # always even number of elements since $ALNUM matches in pairs; and always has a sentinel pair
    my @b = $b =~ m/$ALNUM/g;
    my $cmp = 0;
    my $min_ab = (@a < @b) ? @a : @b;
    my $i;
    print STDERR "comparing (<".join("> <", @a).">) with (<".join("> <", @b).">)" if $verbose;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $min_ab; ++$i) {  # advance by 2; once here
        $cmp = $a[$i] cmp $b[$i];   # compare alphas
        last if $cmp;    # end if we found unequals

        ++$i;       # advance once more here
        # compare nums
        my $lenai = length($a[$i]);
        my $lenbi = length($b[$i]);

        # deal with Extra credit: prefix "0" to the shorter num
        if ($lenai < $lenbi) {
            $a[$i] = ("0" x ($lenbi-$lenai)).$a[$i];
        } elsif ($lenbi < $lenai) {
            $b[$i] = ("0" x ($lenai-$lenbi)).$b[$i];
        }

        $cmp = $a[$i] cmp $b[$i]; # note: stringwise compare of nums
        last if $cmp;    # end if we found unequals
    }
    print STDERR " = $cmp\n" if $verbose;
    return $cmp;
}

print join "\n", sort sordidcmp @in;
print "\n" if @in;  # guard against empty input
```

My questions are:

1. I observed that the match `@a = $a =~ m/$ALNUM/g` always produces a sentinel pair of ("", ""). Is the above code relying on undocumented behaviour? I could not find (read: understand) this from the `perlop`, `perlretut`, and `perlre` perldocs.
2. Can you help simplify the sordidcmp subroutine? Perl golf would be nice, but a more maintainable version is what I would be interested in. Of course, links to other solutions/implementations are welcome.

Comment: When did SO turn into a combination of [codereview.se] and [codegolf.se]

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks for the links, I did not know about them.

Comment: Found a Perl golf challenge dated Jul-2002 @ [http://thospel.home.xs4all.nl/golf/challenge.html](http://thospel.home.xs4all.nl/golf/challenge.html) as "Human sort" with some commentary on the golf solutions as well!

Comment: More spoilers: [`Sort::Key`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Key), [`Sort::Naturally`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Naturally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I observed that the match @a = $a =~ m/$ALNUM/g always produces a sentinel pair. Is the above code relying on undocumented behaviour?

I don't know what you mean by "sentinel pair", but that will always return two values per match since you have two captures.

> Can you help simplify the sordidcmp subroutine?

You could replace `sort sordidcmp` with [Sort::Key::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Key::Natural)'s `natsort`.

Comment: clarified sentinel pair as ("", ""). Running the above script after setting $verbose = 1; would print the matches and always a last pair of <> <>. And, thank you for the `Sort::Key::Natural` link.

Comment: Your pattern successfully matches the zero-length strings at the end of the string.

Comment: I didn't check to see if it supports very long numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data=qw(File1 AFile10 afile10 file10 10 File11 File10 File2 File3 File3A
         File3X File4 File5 File6 File12 File8 File999);

my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
          sort {  $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] 
                        ||
                  $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}
          map  { [$_, $_=~/(\d+)/] }
       @data;

print join("\n", @sorted)."\n";
```

Prints:

```
10
AFile10
File1
File10
File11
File12
File2
File3
File3A
File3X
File4
File5
File6
File8
File999
afile10
file10
```

If you do not want to use the numeric value for the capture group, you can a) strip the leading zeros; b) substitute the length of the group and c) use its lexicographic sort of the group and do something like this:

```
my @data=qw(File1 AFile10 afile10 file10 10 File11 File10 File2 File3 File3A
         File3X File4 File5 File6 File12 File8 File999 File000010);

my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
          sort {  $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] 
                        ||
                  length($a->[2]) <=> length($b->[2])
                        ||
                   $a->[2] cmp $b->[2]}
          map  { [$_, $_=~/(^[^\d]*)0*(\d+)/] }
       @data;

print join("\n", @sorted)."\n";
```

Prints:

```
10
AFile10
File1
File2
File3
File3A
File3X
File4
File5
File6
File8
File10
File000010
File11
File12
File999
afile10
file10
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider putting `AFile` after `File` a “more natural” order, regardless of the numeric suffix.

Comment: Also, you need to change `$a->[2]` and `$b->[2]` to `$a->[0]` and `$b->[0]`, respectively (turn on warnings and you'll see why). Finally, this solution ignores the requirement that "the algorithm may only rely on comparing characters; to avoid overflow problems with very long numbers **it must not convert substrings of digits into their numerical values.**"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I think I have addressed your comments with my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @drewk: again, it works with one alpha and one num. what if there are more? sorry, the question did not explicitly mention about the cases of repeating alphas and nums.

Comment: @drewk: Thanks for the link to `Schwartzian transform`.

Answer (score 1):

How about a comparator version:

```
sub alnum_compar($$)
{
    my ($a0, $b0) = (shift, shift);
    my $a = $a0;
    my $b = $b0;
    my $c;

    while (length($a) && length($b)) {
        my @a = $a =~ /^(\d+|\D+)(.*)$/;
        my @b = $b =~ /^(\d+|\D+)(.*)$/;

        if ($a[0] =~ /^\d/ && $b[0] =~ /^\d/) {
            $c = int($a[0]) - int($b[0]);
        } else {
            $c = $a[0] cmp $b[0];
        }
        return $c if ($c != 0);

        $a = $a[1];
        $b = $b[1];
    }

    return length($a0) - length($b0);
}
```

Test:

```
my @data=qw(File1 AFile10 afile10 file10 10 File11 File10 File2 File3 File3A
         File3X File4 File5 File6 File12 File8 File999 File000010);
print join("\n", sort alnum_compar @data) . "\n";
```

Results:

```
10
AFile10
File1
File2
File3
File3A
File3X
File4
File5
File6
File8
File10
File000010
File11
File12
File999
afile10
file10
```

Comment: This isn't much of a review. Can you at least explain why this is better please?

Comment: I thought this can be one of solutions since it shows its algorithm clearer than the others.

I'm sorry if it didn't match the review, I tried to answer the original article, it said "links to other solutions/implementations are welcome".